# LINQ filter query with groubBy

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm currently working on a .NET Core application.

I need to filter a LINQ query by the following requirements:

- Id: if there is no ContactId, select Id only one time (1)
- Id and ContactId: if exists filter Id (1) and add Id and Contact Id pair (1, 1)
- An Id and ContactId pair must be **unique**, but can vary like: (1, 1), (1, 5)
- empty objects must be removed

```
public class SearchResult
{
    public int? Id {get; set;}
    public int? ContactId {get; set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var searchResults = new List<SearchResult>
        {
            new SearchResult { Id = 1 },
            new SearchResult { },
            new SearchResult { Id = 2 }, // yes
            new SearchResult { Id = 3 }, // yes
            new SearchResult { Id = 4 }, // yes
            new SearchResult { Id = 5 },
                        
            new SearchResult { Id = 5, ContactId = 3 }, // yes
            new SearchResult { Id = 1, ContactId = 1 }, // yes
            new SearchResult { Id = 1, ContactId = 5 }, // yes
            new SearchResult { Id = 8, ContactId = 4 }, // yes
            
            new SearchResult { Id = 1 }, 
            new SearchResult { Id = 2 }, 
            new SearchResult { Id = 10 }, // yes
            new SearchResult { Id = 11 }, // yes
            new SearchResult { Id = 12 }, // yes
        };
        
        // unfortunately this LINQ query does not work correctly:
        var result = searchResults
                 .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                 .ThenBy(x => x.ContactId)
                 .GroupBy(p => new { p.Id, p.ContactId })
                 .Select(x => x.First());
        
        foreach(var sr in result){         
            Console.WriteLine(sr.Id + " " + sr.ContactId);
        }       
    }
```

The expected result should be:

```
1 1
1 5
2 
3 
4  
5 3
8 4
10 
11 
12
```

Unfortunately my LINQ query does not work correctly.

Do you know how to solve this issue and to filter the LINQ query according to the rules?

Comment: of course it doesn't work, there is nothing in your code to even try to do the tasks.

Comment: I tried to filter with a where clause - but I only got the exceptions...

Comment: You need to explicitly eliminate the null Ids, and when you order a list nulls will be first in the list.

Comment: show us the code that causes you issues along with the error messages

Comment: This is unclear, What do you mean by: Id: if there is no ContactId, select Id: (2), (3) - only one time? What is (2), (3)?

Comment: if in the given list is (1), (1,1), (1,5) it should take (1,1), (1,5)

Comment: so do you mean, if not contact, only take ID 2 and 3, and none other? But then why your example shows also 4, 10, etc... Did you mean all IDs but 1?

Comment: @LaurentGabiot the 2 and 3 examples are misleading, OP meant *"select Id: (2), (3), ... and so on"*

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’d like to clarify. Since its rules contradicts its sample result, only him can confirm which one is true.

Comment: sorry guys, i changed the description

Comment: @Bender, are you waiting for a better answer? It is nice to mark the answer that you think is good, so don't forget to do it. Also Dmitry answered first, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dmitry Bychenko solution's is good except for a bug:

It doesn't remove duplicate pairs.

**EDIT** this is no longer the case, the bug was corrected.

Which seems mandatory as per:

> An Id and ContactId pair must be unique, but can vary like: (1, 1),
> (1, 5)

In order to do so, you can use the `Distinct` operator, but since SearchResult is a class, `Distinct` will not compare the value of each instance, but its reference. So I simply projected each SearchResult to a value tuple to have a quick way to compare on value and not reference.

```cs
var result = searchResults
    .Where(e => e.ContactId.HasValue || e.Id.HasValue)
    .Select(e => (Id: e.Id, ContactId: e.ContactId))
    .GroupBy(e => e.Id)
    .Select(g => g.Any(e => e.ContactId.HasValue)
       ? g.Where(e => e.ContactId.HasValue).Distinct()
       : g.Take(1))
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .Select(e => new SearchResult
        {
            Id = e .Id,
            ContactId = e.ContactId
        });
```

Also you didn't specify the case where a SearchResult would have a ContactId and no Id.
The behavior of the current code it to accept such a pair.

If you want to filter these, simply change this line

```cs
.Where(e => e.ContactId.HasValue || e.Id.HasValue)
```

by

```cs
.Where(e => e.Id.HasValue)
```

Below is a full Linqpad Query for your to try. I added duplicates and SearchResults with a null Id and non null ContactId

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    
    var searchResults = new List<SearchResult>
    {
        new SearchResult { Id = 1 },
        new SearchResult { },
        new SearchResult { ContactId = 45}, // IS accepted, but the behavior was not specified.
        new SearchResult { ContactId = 45},
        new SearchResult { ContactId = 42},
        new SearchResult { ContactId = 45},
        new SearchResult { ContactId = 45},
        new SearchResult { Id = 2 }, // yes
        new SearchResult { Id = 3 }, // yes
        new SearchResult { Id = 4 }, // yes
        new SearchResult { Id = 5 },
        new SearchResult { Id = 5 },
        new SearchResult { Id = 5 },
        new SearchResult { Id = 5 },

        new SearchResult { Id = 5, ContactId = 3 }, // yes
        new SearchResult { Id = 1, ContactId = 1 }, // yes
        new SearchResult { Id = 1, ContactId = 5 }, // yes
        new SearchResult { Id = 8, ContactId = 4 }, // yes
        new SearchResult { Id = 8, ContactId = 4 },
        new SearchResult { Id = 8, ContactId = 4 },
        new SearchResult { Id = 8, ContactId = 4 },
        
        new SearchResult { Id = 1 },
        new SearchResult { Id = 2 },
        new SearchResult { Id = 10 }, // yes
        new SearchResult { Id = 11 }, // yes
        new SearchResult { Id = 12 }, // yes
    };

    var result = searchResults
    .Where(e => e.ContactId.HasValue || e.Id.HasValue)
    .Select(e => (Id: e.Id, ContactId: e.ContactId))
    .GroupBy(e => e.Id)
    .Select(g => g.Any(e => e.ContactId.HasValue)
       ? g.Where(e => e.ContactId.HasValue).Distinct()
       : g.Take(1))
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .Select(e => new SearchResult
        {
            Id = e .Id,
            ContactId = e.ContactId
        })
    .Dump();
}

public class SearchResult
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int? ContactId { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**
As per asker request:

It is possible to get rid of the tuple projections, but still have the benefit of the `Distinct` method.

One solution is to have the SearchResult class implement the IEquatable Interface:

```cs
public class SearchResult : IEquatable<SearchResult>
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int? ContactId { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(SearchResult other)
    {
        return Id == other.Id && ContactId == other.ContactId;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashId = Id == null ? 0 : Id.GetHashCode();
        int hashContactId = ContactId == null ? 0 : ContactId.GetHashCode();

        return hashId ^ hashContactId;
    }
}
```

The query is then simplified into:

```cs
var result = searchResults
    .Where(e => e.ContactId.HasValue || e.Id.HasValue)
    .GroupBy(e => e.Id)
    .Select(g => g.Any(e => e.ContactId.HasValue)
       ? g.Where(e => e.ContactId.HasValue).Distinct()
       : g.Take(1))
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Comment: thanks, that's a good point. It works fine, but I still need to flatten the IEnumerable<(a,b)> to an IEnumerable<SearchResult>()...

Comment: See my edited answer. There is no need to flatten, it is already flattened (the SelectMany does the flattening). It is just a very trivial Projection with Select. I thought it was too trivial to add.

Comment: ah yes, that works very well. In my real application I do have more properties in SearchResult than just two. It feels a bit clumsy to first group all properties and then project all properties again - but I guess that's the way to go. Merci beaucoup!

Comment: Then the best is for your SerachResult class to implement IEquatable<T> so that the Distinct operator works and get rid of the tuple projections

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks again! Your solution works perfectly fine - I chose it as the right anwer, because in my case I prefer IEquatable over IEqualityComparer. Altough both solutions would work.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest something like this. Here we `GroupBy` and then *analyze each group*. Finally, we *flatten* `group`s back into `IEnumerable<SearchResult>` (please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gMKuXC))

For removing duplicates we should know how to compare items for *equality* and then call `Distinct`. We can implement IEqualityComparer for this:

```
private class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<SearchResult> {
  public bool Equals(SearchResult x, SearchResult y) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return true;
    else if (null == x || null == y)
      return false;

    return x.Id == y.Id && x.ContactId == y.ContactId;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(SearchResult obj) => (obj != null && obj.Id.HasValue)
    ? obj.Id.Value
    : 0; 
}
```

Final Code:

```
  var result = searchResults
    .Where(item => item.ContactId.HasValue || item.Id.HasValue)
    .Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer()) // remove duplicates
    .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
    .Select(group => group.Any(item => item.ContactId.HasValue)
       ? group.Where(item => item.ContactId.HasValue)
       : group.Take(1))
    .SelectMany(group => group);
```

Let's have a look:

```
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
   .Select(item => $"{item.Id} {item.ContactId}")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
1 1
1 5
2 
3 
4 
5 3
8 4
10 
11 
12
```

Comment: Nice, is there any reason not using group.Take(1) instead of new SearchResult[] { group.First() }?

Comment: @Laurent Gabiot: thank you for the suggestion: `Take(1)` is better then `new SearchResult[] { group.First() }`

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! It's a very good direction - unfortunately the dublicates are still in the list, as indicated here.

Comment: @Bender.: Sorry, my bad, it seems that I've omitted `Distinct()`. I've edited the code

Comment: Thanks again! Your solution works perfectly fine - Though in my case I chose IEquatable over IEqualityComparer. Altough both solutions would work fine.